# Notepad++ how to add zero after decimal just two digits only

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to use Notepad++ find and replace feature.

if after decimal more two digits like this 8:11:4,513 just ignore it.
replace only two digits after decimal 8:14:1,58 and add zero like this 8:14:1,058
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ you can search /replace with regex.

For me it would be the best option and the search regex would be:

```
^(.*\d,)(\d{2})$
```

and the replace expression:

```
\10\2
```

Explanations:

- `^(.*\d,)` -> Create left group with everything and a digit followed by a comma.
- `(\d{2})$` -> second group (right) matching the 2 digits afet the comma
- `\10\2` -> relapce by 0

It worked well with the sample provided.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\d,\K(?=\d{2}\b)`
- Replace with: `0`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\d          : a digit
,           : a comma
\K          : forget all we have seen until this position
(?=         : start lookahead, make sure we have after
  \d{2}     : 2 digits
  \b        : word boundary to make sure we don't have another digit after
)           : end lookahead
```

**Result for given example:**

```
8:11:4,513
8:14:1,058
```